# Internet not working in Virtual machine (Ubuntu 14.10 ) running on windows 10 host

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, vmware-workstation

I was using windows 8.1 and had installed VMWare Workstation 11.0 on it. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in it. Internet was working fine then.

I am connected on my host m/c via Wifi.

I then updated to Windows 10 recently. After that internet run fine on Windows but Ubuntu in virtual box remains offline. I am a novice in ubuntu. Any help is appreciated. I tried few online solutions but nothing works.

ifconfig shows following:

```
gaurav@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:b2:15:73  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17703 (17.7 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1154 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1154 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:96264 (96.2 KB)  TX bytes:96264 (96.2 KB)
```

Comment: From memory, VMware Workstation hooks into the network setup during installation.  By upgrading to Windows 10, it probably reset that networking config back so that the virtual networking won't work.  Try reinstalling/repairing VMware Workstation, or at least reconfiguring the networking portion to get it to recreate the config.

Comment: @DarkMoon  I did reinstall the VMWare workstation but still the problem persists.

Comment: Did you check the networking setup in VMware workstation?  There should be (I believe) a VMNet0 in Bridged mode connected to your wireless NIC?  Also, out of curiousity, why not just use Hyper-V, which is built in to Win10?  :-P

Comment: Even choosing VMnet0 doesn't work.. :(

Comment: Well, check that the network is set correctly in Ubutu. Here's a link to the Ubuntu doco on Network Manager, which is what Ubuntu uses by default. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

Simply Re-installing VMWare Workstation solved the problem for me. I think when I updated to Windows 10, settings got reset which caused the problem. Reinstalling VMWare workstation restored those settings.